# Angular Gridster prevent resize

Tags: angularjs, resize, gridster

Maybe someone knows how to stop resize of gridster element?
egz. code:

```
$scope.$on('gridster-item-resized', function (ee, item) {
  if(isTooSmall(item.getElementSizeX())
  {
      //do not resize
  }
      //else resize.
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to set maxSizeX, maxSizeY, minSizeX, minSizeY for each widget. So, if you'll use these parameters you'll be able to avoid unwanted sizes for widgets.